# What are a set of standard industry tools that can be used to define a complete CI/CD pipeline in the Local linux machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am extremely new to the CI/CD world. I want to set up a CI/CD pipeline in my local machine.

Step 1 : I want to initialize a git repo locally in my machine and not push it online.

Step 2: I want to trigger a build anytime i commit something into the local repo.

.
.
.

Note :Assume I want to do the entire thing without an internet connection.(Not while downloading the required software of course).

What are the set of tools(eg jenkins) that can be downloaded locally and make a mock CI/CD pipeline for learning purposes.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options for local CI/CD testing:

1. [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) - A local Kubernetes cluster designed for local testing.  There are some great interactive [tutorials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/) they provide to get you started.  Just be aware that if you do not want an internet connection you will need any base Docker images you are using downloaded during your initial setup (e.g. if you are building a .net core project you will need the .net core sdk base Docker image already downloaded).
2. [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/) - A popular open source CI/CD tool that meets your requirements.
3. [Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/installing-bamboo-on-linux-289276792.html) - A commercial CI/CD tool built by Atlassian.  The link goes to the Linux installation instructions.  It can run locally without internet.
4. [Team City](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/installing-and-configuring-the-teamcity-server.html#Installing-TeamCity-bundled-with-Tomcat-servlet-container-(Linux,-macOS,-Windows)) - A commercial CI/CD tool built by Jetbrains.  The link goes to the Linux installation instructions.  It can also be run locally without internet.
5. Linux command line tooling.  Learning the various command for moving files around as scripts in your CI/CD tool is a very useful skillset to learn.

You can use these tools together.  For example, you may want to have Jenkins/Bamboo trigger on your repository changes, build a container, and deploy the container using Minikube.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it on a current cloud-ready stack, you could [Set up a CI/CD pipeline with kubernetes](https://www.linux.com/blog/learn/chapter/Intro-to-Kubernetes/2017/5/set-cicd-pipeline-kubernetes-part-1-overview).

If you're not interested in that, you could also install jenkins locally and get started from there.